# detect if bluetooth device is connected in iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

is it possible to detect if a bluetooth device is connected in your app code?  I have a bluetooth device that works with my app but I want to show or hide it's capability based on whether a bluetooth device is connected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use EAAccessory for this:

[EAAccessory Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is a blog post that shows some examples of how to use it:

[iPhone: External Accessory Framework snippets](http://www.ericd.net/2009/07/iphone-external-accessory-framework.html)

There is also a demo of the functionality here:

[EADemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079)

Comment: Note that this will only work for MFI (Made for iP*) certified devices.