# Detect if bluetooth device connected on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, bluetooth

Is there a way to check whether or not a Bluetooth device is connected.  I am working on an app that has both Bluetooth and non Bluetooth hardware that connects and want to hide a tab if Bluetooth isn't connected.

The problem is that the bluetooth connects and starts streaming, then the device authenticates and if the user opens the app before the authentication is finished, then my bluetooth tab doesn't show and the user will have to close the app then reopen it. It seems like a small annoyance I know, but I was just curious if it was possible to detect the status (connected or disconnected) for the Bluetooth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect if bluetooth device is connected in iPad application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473139/detect-if-bluetooth-device-is-connected-in-ipad-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can check CBCentralManager Class in [CoreBlueTooth Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html)

Comment: Isn't CoreBluetooth just for Low Energy devices?